# 'View Full Site' add ?m=0 to all inside pages

Tags: .htaccess, mobile

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ ^(.*)\.php$?m=0 [R=301,L]
```

I want all inside pages to be rewritten to ?m=0 coming from SITEDOTCOM?m=0

So basically if someone lands comes to the full site using the trailing ? i want all the links to be ?m=0

??

REASON: Mobile redirect Full Site button works once. Does not work if user clicks on something. returns to mobile site.

my code looks like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.Site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Tried top code return infinite loop.? thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This line here:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
```

should probably be checking the query string instead as well:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}       !(^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
```

Because the cookie isn't sent to the browser until the server **responds**, by that time the redirect is already made. The two `CO` lines creates a cookie to be sent to the browser, and immediately you redirect them to mobile before there's a response.

---

How about something like this? Change the redirect rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        mobile=1(;|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}       ^$
RewriteRule ^ http://m.Site.com%{REQUEST_URI}?mobile=1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        \mobile=0(;|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}       ^$
RewriteRule ^ http://Site.com%{REQUEST_URI}?mobile=0 [R,L]
```

Comment: that wont work for me because the mobile site is only 2 pages. adding the & makes the mobile site 404. so i want the htaccess to if then like this..

Comment: click full site "mainsite?m=0" ----  arrive at full site homepage?m=0 ---- then if you click on a button other than the homepage all php pages other than homepage should end in ?m=0

Comment: @Sparxx "*so i want the htaccess to if then like this..click full site "mainsite?m=0"*", what does that mean? The `&` in the rule simply matches the query string. It's either the beginning of the query string or a part of it.